# Laravel SChema Builder Increments syntax

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have seen on the web some people adding `true` to the increments method whilst creating migrations. What does this do?

According to the offical Laravel 4.2 api, increments only accepts the field name as a string:

> Fluent increments(string $column)
>
> Create a new auto-incrementing integer column on the table.
>   Parameters
>   string    $column
>   Return Value
>   Fluent

Comment: Additional arguments to a function will simply be ignored by that function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the documentation says, the `increcemnts`-method accepts only one argument which is the name of the column.

But `increments($column)` is only a shortcut for `unsignedInteger($column, true)`, where the second argument specifies whether the column should be auto-incremented. So you probably just confused them.

Don't forget that Laravel is open source, so whenever you're not sure about how something works under the hood, just [have a look at the source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php#L341-L350).

Comment: Really appreciated that source code link. That gets right to the heart of the matter. Wish the docs were more descriptive with things of this nature.